# posting on facebook wall using sso

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an application that requires facebook integration using Single Sign On. I have successfully integrated and got my friends list. But not able to posting message on wall. while posting message giving me error:

**An error occurred with Single Sign On. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 11
API Error Description: This method is deprecated
Error Message: Display=wap dialogs have been deprecated. You can temporarily enable them by disabling the "july_2012" migration. They will stop working permanently on July 1, 2012.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to actually temporarily enable the changes?

If so...

- go to your app's Facebook page which is https://developers.facebook.com/apps when you are logged into Facebook
- Click "Ëdit App" (near top right corner),
- Under Settings (left column) click "Advanced",
- Scroll down to the "Migrations Settings" section.
- Enable the "July 2012  breaking changes" (2nd from bottom in the Migrations Settings section)

Doing the above will only temporarily solve your problems (by the look of it until July 1st 2012).  I recommend looking at the examples in the facebook-android-sdk [(available at Git Hub)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).  While [I have had problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073426/is-it-possible-to-extend-facebook-tokens-with-extendaccesstokenifneeded-in-an-an) with some aspects of the Hackbook example, I have found the wall posting  code to work well.