# What is the  code for getting a refreshed Facebook token in an Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am developing an Android app.  With the impending deprecation of Facebook's offline_access permission I am trying to use the Graph API to extend the Facebook token.

```
        https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
        client_id=APP_ID&
        client_secret=APP_SECRET&
        grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
        fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Can anyone provide detailed code that demonstrates how to implement the code above into an android app and obtain the refreshed Facebook token?

Thank you for your time.

**Update Two:**

Progress (I think)!

Using the full URL with the facebook request method results in the base URL being added to the the beginning of the URL
So instead of

```
String refreshUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=12345678910&client_secret=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="+currentAccessToken;
```

should use

```
String refreshUrl = "oauth/access_token?client_id=12345678910&client_secret=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="+currentAccessToken;
```

However I am now getting the response  {"error":{"message":"Error validating application. Invalid application ID.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}

**Update One:**

Here is what I have I tried. The code completes, that is OnComplete on the listerner is called, BUT the response does not contain a new access token or expiry value.

```
    void refreshWithGraph() {
        AsyncFacebookRunner extendingAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

        //the variable currentAccessToken is obtained after authorisation is complete using currentAccessToken = facebook.getAccessToken();

        String refreshUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=12345678910&client_secret=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="+currentAccessToken;


    extendingAsyncRunner.request(refreshUrl, parameters, new RefreshListener(), null );
   }
```

Here is my version of RefreshListener...

```
  //REFRESH LISTENER
    public class RefreshListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, Object state) {


            try {
               final JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {             
                        tvRefreshResponse.setText("IN REFRESH LISTENER ONCOMPLETE\nResponse is " + response);
                        tvRefreshToken.setText("IN REFRESH LISTENER ONCOMPLETE\nToken is " + facebook.getAccessToken());
                        tvRefreshExpiry.setText("IN REFRESH LISTENER ONCOMPLETE\nFacebook expiry is " + millisecToDate(facebook.getAccessExpires()));

                    }

                }); //end runOnUiThread



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvRefreshResponse.setText("IN REFRESH LISTENER ONCOMPLETE CAUGHT JSON EXCEPTION \nResponse is " + response);

                            }

                         }); //end runOnUiThread

            } catch (FacebookError fe) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvRefreshResponse.setText("IN REFRESH LISTENER ONCOMPLETE CAUGHT FACEBOOK ERROR \nResponse is " + response);

                            }

                         }); //end runOnUiThread
            } //end catch Facebook error

        }  //end onComplete


        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            tvRefreshResponse.setText("IN REFRESH LISTENER IOEXCEPTION \nException is "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            tvRefreshResponse.setText("IN REFRESH LISTENER FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION \nException is "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            tvRefreshResponse.setText("IN REFRESH MALFORMED URL \nException is "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            tvRefreshResponse.setText("IN REFRESH ONFACEBOOK ERROR \nException is "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());

        }
    } //end RefreshListener
```

The code completes, that is OnComplete on the listerner is called, BUT the response does not contain a new access token or expiry value.  The response is...

```
 {"id":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/oauth\/access_token","shares":78,"comments":1}
```

When I put the same URL (with a alphanumeric current token value) into a web browser the response DOES include an access token.

---

**Related Info**

Facebook's offline_access permission will be deprecated on 1st of May, 2012

Please don't suggest using the extendAccessTokenIfNeeded function in onResume() instead. [I am also having trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073426/is-it-possible-to-extend-facebook-tokens-with-extendaccesstokenifneeded-in-an-an) with that and it is the reason why I am looking into the Graph API token refreshing  :-)

***Related Stack Overflow Questions***

[Is it possible to extend Facebook tokens with extendAccessTokenIfNeeded in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073426/is-it-possible-to-extend-facebook-tokens-with-extendaccesstokenifneeded-in-an-an) (my question)

[How would offline_access work after deprecation after May 1st?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930311/how-would-offline-access-work-after-deprecation-after-may-1st)

[Facebook access token can not be extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190276/facebook-access-token-can-not-be-extended)

[Protecting app secret for extendAccessToken usage (Java/Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549689/protecting-app-secret-for-extendaccesstoken-usage-java-android)

***Relevant Facebook links***

[Facebook Android Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

[Facebook offline_access permission deprecation](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Comment: With all the links above, why do you need any more detailed information? Looks like you have enough documentation to implement this..

Comment: You would think I could work it out, but no.  :-(  All the easy question on Stack Overflow get fully answered very quickly so I guess this isn't as easy as it first seems...

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, I'm a bit confused - looks like you have everything to get it done - and it's simple. But let me try to answer your question. Here is the code from my C# project where I extend app's token with my comments in case you are not familiar with C# languages and classes:

```
string currentToken = "token from somewhere";

// WebClient is used to send GET request to the given URL
// and receive the response
using (var req = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    // create URL string and fill it in with data (app Id, secret, and current token)
    var extendTokenUrl = string.Format(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={2}",
        FB_APP_ID,
        FB_APP_SECRET,
        currentToken);

    // send GET request and download the response
    var response = req.DownloadString(extendTokenUrl);

    // if all is good, response will be a string which looks like this:
    // access_token=<<THE TOKEN GOES HERE>>
    var newToken = response.Substring("access_token=".Length);

    // now save newToken in your DB INSTEAD of currentToken - 
    // so all calls will be made with extended token
    SaveTokenInDB(newToken);
}
```

hope that helps, and translating this into Java should be straightforward.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response.  I am confused myself!  What I'm told is an easy task is not getting any response from Android developers - even with the 100 point bounty!  My coding problem is that the response from Facebook does not contain an access key.  However, When I just put the whole URL in a browser  I do get an access key. I have updated my answer to include my previous attempts.

Comment: I noticed right away that you parse JSON in your RefreshListener - but that's wrong, I believe. You are not getting JSON back but just a raw string. Also - if you paste value of "String refreshUrl" in the browser, will you get proper token? Are you 100% sure you are doing GET request (instead of POST)? Also - do you have sources for AsyncFacebookRunner? can you find out WHERE it actually sends HTTP request - and log exact URL, HTTP method there? Also - if you do NOT use AsyncFacebookRunner but just standard HTTP request component - will it work?

Comment: Thank you, I'm making progress...When I alter the code in the SDK's Util.java code (which is the class that actually does the http request) I start getting the same response as from typing an address in browser. But I now realise that the expiry figure is very small (5143168). When I refresh the figure always decreases... Any ideas on this?  Response example... access_token=AAAEparERUxABAFSPLEI8VNAwo8FLsxOpR6bZAgyeRxj0JAtGBBqMv5y3gnMkvy0TMCrnKuF0Jp6S1DSpiO8mmiy3JMBV2XZASAimYwZDZD&expires=5143168

Comment: expires=5143168 - it's number of seconds for how long token is valid, in seconds. It's 59-something days - which is the duration FB promises for the extended token. So looks like all is good.

Comment: Thank you.  I realise that the token does not actually refresh.  When I attempt to refresh with a few seconds in between refreshes I get the same token and the expiry goes down by just a few seconds.  I'm think I read somewhere (can't find where) that tokens can only be refreshed once every 24 hours?  Do you think there could be another reason?

Comment: unfortunately i do not have an official link, i also have a feeling I read somewhere about 1 day before token gets actually refreshed but I do not remember exactly. Anyway, just give it a try tomorrow :)

Comment: Will do.  Thank you for all your help.  I have assigned the bounty (as it was about to expire) and I will mark question correct after I have refreshed token with a 24 hour gap between refreshes.  Fingers crossed!